# Notification when use delete shared facebook link from your app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It simple question, if user give me permission to post on his wall by api and then user delete that post, can i have notification for that?

Comment: Maybe using real time update:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know no, you'd need to poll the post ID using the user's access token to see if it's still there